# OpenCobol Makefile

Tags: makefile, cobol

I am trying to compile an OpenCobol program using make. I am always getting "make: Nothing to be done for test1.cob". Here is my makefile. I had put a TAB before cobc. But still I am getting that message. Please help.
Thanks.

```
COBCWARN = -W
%: %.cob
    cobc $(COBCWARN) -free -x $^ -o $@
```

And here is my cobol program.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. TEST1.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   DISPLAY 'Hello world!'.
   STOP RUN.
```

Comment: What command are you running to invoke make?  The above makefile is not complete: by itself it won't do anything.

Comment: @MadScientist: I am using Vim. I am using ':make %' to compile. What should I put into the makefile to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile contains no actual targets.  You have defined only a pattern rule which tells make how to build targets that match the pattern.  But make doesn't go looking for targets out on the filesystem that could match the pattern, it only checks the pattern against targets that have been specifically requested.

You don't have any specific targets (files) listed in your makefile, so the only way make can know about a target is if you give the target to be built on the command line.

You are running this command from within vim, using the `%` special token, which expands to the name of the file currently being edited.  That means you are running the command:

```
make test1.cob
```

because you are editing the file `test1.cob`.  So, you are telling make "please try to create the target (file) `test1.cob`".  But, that file already exists (it's the file you're writing).  So make says "nothing to do".

If you run make and ask it to create the target you really want created, it will work:

```
make test1
```

Now the file `test1` doesn't exist, and make can find a pattern rule that knows how to build it, so make will run that rule.

Alternatively, you can edit your makefile to add the specific target, like this:

```
COBCWARN = -W

test1: test1.cob

%: %.cob
        cobc $(COBCWARN) -free -x $^ -o $@
```

Then you can run `make` with no arguments at all.  Without any command line arguments, make will look in the makefile for explicit targets and find `test1` as the first one.  It sees that there is a rule (the pattern rule) that matches that target, so it will build that target.

*UPDATE*

If you want to allow a simple command `make` to build multiple programs, write your makefile like this:

```
COBCWARN = -W

all: test1 test2 test3
.PHONY: all

%: %.cob
        cobc $(COBCWARN) -free -x $^ -o $@
```

Now from vim you can just say `:!make` and that's it.

If you run `make` with no arguments then it will find the first explicit target in the makefile and build that.  In this example the first target is `all`, and its prerequisites are the possible programs to build.  To build each one make sees that it can apply the pattern rule, and so it will do so (if the `.cob` file has been modified since the last time the program was built).

Comment: In that case, how can I pass the filenames to the makefile? Now, what I do to work it - ":make %:r" to compile in Vim.

Comment: This is a question for vim users, it has nothing to do with make.  I don't use vim (I use Emacs), but from the documentation I read I think you want `:! make %<` to pass make the file name without an extension.

Comment: @Joydeep The rule `%: %.cob` tells make that it can create an executable (more specifically, a name with no extension) if it matches a name with a .cob extension. `make myprogram` would try and make `myprogram`, if it finds a `myprogram.cob` it will use the rule `cobc -free -x ...` using `myprogram.cob` as input and generating `myprogram`.  Use any name you like, and pass the name to make.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That makes it clear. But is it possible to compile multiple programs?

Comment: @Joydeep Yep.  But you'll need to add targets and rules.  Something like `project: program1.cob program2.cob (newline, tab) cobc -x program1.cob program2.cob` then `make project`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to pass bash argument "$@"? 
I understand I should ask this in different thread.
Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.